# Java applet to play SPEEX files from URL

Tags: java, javasound, speex, jspeex

I am coding a java applet which will play an Speex (.SPX) file from a URL. I don't have any experience with the Java Sound API's. The JSpeex documentation was very unhelpful.
I managed to piece together some code, but so far with no success. So far I have this:

```
AudioInputStream speexInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new Speex2PcmAudioInputStream(speexInputStream, AUDIO_FORMAT, speexInputStream.getFrameLength());
DataLine.Info di=new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioInputStream.getFormat());
Clip c = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(di);
System.out.println("opening clip...");
c.open(audioInputStream);
System.out.println("playing clip...");
c.start();
```

However, the clip will not open. (It prints "opening clip..." and then blocks). What have I done wrong?

P.s I am working with Eclipse